# text-chat xmpp message stanzas never make it to the network - iphone project using libjingle

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, google-talk, libjingle

i thought it'd be better to rephrase.  my earlier formulation of my question could have been better focused.  the trouble with presence notifications, while real and still recurring, is kind of minor.  the things i haven't figured out yet i can fake or work around.  much less of a concern than getting basic text chat messages moving between users.

again, still fairly new with this combo of tech flavors - using libjingle as the heart (and liver and kidneys...) of an iphone xmpp/jabber app.  got the sign on part, the presence notification/roster updating business actually seems to be working more or less as it should.  but xmpp text chat message stanzas seem to vanish before making it out on the wire.  capturing other network traffic, and perusing the pretty packets, i yeah, i can see the exchanges for sign on,  etc. that got us going, but then nothing for chat.

i've checked and double checked how i'm putting together the stanzas, attributes, namespaces, etc.  everything looks jim-dandy to me.  i can see that a message is getting queued in the libjingle internal infrastructure.  but no results on the ethernet.

hoping somebody who has played around with this stuff before might remember a similar stumbling block and can offer up a hint, suggestion, or pointer in the right direction.

thanks for any help.

mike